# Appending to an array depending on amount of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

here is my code currently:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#submitBtn").on("click", submitted);
   $(".add-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    })
    
    $(".remove-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container div").eq($(".container div").length - 1).remove();
    })
    
  $('#amount').on('change', function() {
    var containerEl = $(".container");
    containerEl.empty();
    var startingNumberOfLines = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < startingNumberOfLines; i++) {
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    }
  });
  $(".add-row-btn").trigger("click");
 })


 var createNewRow = function() {
  var lineTitleEl = $("<input>").attr("placeholder", "enter text here")
    .addClass("line-title");
  var labelEl = $("<label>");
  var inputEl = $("<input>").attr("step", "0.05").attr("type", "number")
    .addClass("line-number");
  var firstNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  firstNumberEl.text("posx: ").attr("class", "first-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var secondNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  secondNumberEl.text("poxy: ").attr("class", "second-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var newRowEl = $("<div>").append(lineTitleEl, firstNumberEl, secondNumberEl);

  return newRowEl;
 }

 function submitted() {
  console.log("submitted");
  $(".container").children("div").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find(".line-title").val();
    var firstNum = $(this).find(".first-number-el input").val();
    var secondNum = $(this).find(".second-number-el input").val();
    console.log('your array is: [{"posx":'+ firstNum + ',"posy":' + secondNum+',"text":"'+ title +'"}]');
  })

 }
 </script>
 <style>
 .line-title {
  width: 259px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  clear: left;
 }

 .line-number {
  width: 45px;
 }

 .container {
  margin: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset style=" margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
   <!--<div>enter amount of text + number boxes:
      <input id="amount" step="1" style=" width: 45px;" type="number" value="1">
    </div>-->
   <div class="container"></div><button class="add-row-btn">Add row</button> <button class="remove-row-btn">Remove row</button> <input class="button" id="submitBtn" style="margin-left: 85%;" type="button" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When there is only 1 row, the code is working correctly as the array is being outputted in the format I would like. However, when there are multiple rows, it outputs the same line again with different variables.

I would like it to look like this:

For example if this was the input
[image]

I would like the output to look like this:

`submitted
your array is: [{"posx":1,"posy":-1,"text":"test1"},{"posx":-0.1,"posy":0.05,"text":"test2"}]`

Another example, if there were 3 rows like so

[image]

I would like the output to look like this:

`submitted
your array is: [{"posx":1,"posy":-1,"text":"test1"},{"posx":-0.1,"posy":0.05,"text":"test2"},{"posx":-0.3,"posy":0.25,"text":"test3"}]`

How can I make the output look like this depending on the amount of rows?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This one was inadvertently answered in a previous post, where I fleshed it out with a much more complete answer, including removal and creation of a  concurrent array. See that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398891/creating-html-content-based-on-value-in-textbox/47399984?noredirect=1#comment81834458_47399984 -- And @qttqtt, any duplicate warnings you get from mods is because this is all part of that same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to save the outputs into an array before printing them. See below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#submitBtn").on("click", submitted);
   $(".add-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    })
    
    $(".remove-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container div").eq($(".container div").length - 1).remove();
    })
    
  $('#amount').on('change', function() {
    var containerEl = $(".container");
    containerEl.empty();
    var startingNumberOfLines = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < startingNumberOfLines; i++) {
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    }
  });
  $(".add-row-btn").trigger("click");
 })


 var createNewRow = function() {
  var lineTitleEl = $("<input>").attr("placeholder", "enter text here")
    .addClass("line-title");
  var labelEl = $("<label>");
  var inputEl = $("<input>").attr("step", "0.05").attr("type", "number")
    .addClass("line-number");
  var firstNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  firstNumberEl.text("posx: ").attr("class", "first-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var secondNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  secondNumberEl.text("poxy: ").attr("class", "second-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var newRowEl = $("<div>").append(lineTitleEl, firstNumberEl, secondNumberEl);

  return newRowEl;
 }

 function submitted() {
console.log("submitted");
var output = [];
$(".container").children("div").each(function () {
 var title = $(this).find(".line-title").val();
 var firstNum = $(this).find(".first-number-el input").val();
 var secondNum = $(this).find(".second-number-el input").val();
 output.push({
  "posx": firstNum,
  "posy": secondNum,
  "text": title
 });
});
console.log('your array is: ' + JSON.stringify(output));
}

 </script>
 <style>
 .line-title {
  width: 259px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  clear: left;
 }

 .line-number {
  width: 45px;
 }

 .container {
  margin: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset style=" margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
   <!--<div>enter amount of text + number boxes:
      <input id="amount" step="1" style=" width: 45px;" type="number" value="1">
    </div>-->
   <div class="container"></div><button class="add-row-btn">Add row</button> <button class="remove-row-btn">Remove row</button> <input class="button" id="submitBtn" style="margin-left: 85%;" type="button" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @zatopeks' but I am a bit late...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#submitBtn").on("click", submitted);
   $(".add-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    })
    
    $(".remove-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container div").eq($(".container div").length - 1).remove();
    })
    
  $('#amount').on('change', function() {
    var containerEl = $(".container");
    containerEl.empty();
    var startingNumberOfLines = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < startingNumberOfLines; i++) {
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    }
  });
  $(".add-row-btn").trigger("click");
 })


 var createNewRow = function() {
  var lineTitleEl = $("<input>").attr("placeholder", "enter text here")
    .addClass("line-title");
  var labelEl = $("<label>");
  var inputEl = $("<input>").attr("step", "0.05").attr("type", "number")
    .addClass("line-number");
  var firstNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  firstNumberEl.text("posx: ").attr("class", "first-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var secondNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  secondNumberEl.text("poxy: ").attr("class", "second-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var newRowEl = $("<div>").append(lineTitleEl, firstNumberEl, secondNumberEl);

  return newRowEl;
 }

 function submitted() {
  console.log("submitted");
     var all_items = []
  $(".container").children("div").each(function() {
       var tmp_item = {
          "text": $(this).find(".line-title").val(),
          "posx": parseFloat($(this).find(".first-number-el input").val()),
          "posy": parseFloat($(this).find(".second-number-el input").val())
       }
       all_items.push(tmp_item)
  })
     console.log('your array is: ' + JSON.stringify(all_items));

 }
 </script>
 <style>
 .line-title {
  width: 259px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  clear: left;
 }

 .line-number {
  width: 45px;
 }

 .container {
  margin: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset style=" margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
   <!--<div>enter amount of text + number boxes:
      <input id="amount" step="1" style=" width: 45px;" type="number" value="1">
    </div>-->
   <div class="container"></div><button class="add-row-btn">Add row</button> <button class="remove-row-btn">Remove row</button> <input class="button" id="submitBtn" style="margin-left: 85%;" type="button" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @urban !  Is there a way to remove the "" only around the integers (for firstNum and secondNum) ?

Comment: You can use `parseFloat()` as above. If you want to force ints look into `parseInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array of objects for each row.

Add some classes to the rows to make them easy to isolate, then map each row

```js
const data = $('.input-row').map(function() {
  const $row = $(this)
  return {
    posx: $row.find('.pos-x').val(),
    posy: $row.find('.pos-y').val(),
    text: $row.find('.line-title').val()
  };
}).get()

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-row">
  <input class="line-title" value="Text 1">
  <input class="line-number pos-x" value="1">
  <input class="line-number pos-y" value="2">
</div>
<div class="input-row">
  <input class="line-title" value="Text 2">
  <input class="line-number pos-x" value="3">
  <input class="line-number pos-y" value="4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at what's happening in submitted(). On each loop you print that line. What you want is to print the formalities ahead of time, then just the {} objects during the loop.

Something like this, probably:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#submitBtn").on("click", submitted);
   $(".add-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    })
    
    $(".remove-row-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $(".container div").eq($(".container div").length - 1).remove();
    })
    
  $('#amount').on('change', function() {
    var containerEl = $(".container");
    containerEl.empty();
    var startingNumberOfLines = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < startingNumberOfLines; i++) {
      $(".container").append(createNewRow());
    }
  });
  $(".add-row-btn").trigger("click");
 })


 var createNewRow = function() {
  var lineTitleEl = $("<input>").attr("placeholder", "enter text here")
    .addClass("line-title");
  var labelEl = $("<label>");
  var inputEl = $("<input>").attr("step", "0.05").attr("type", "number")
    .addClass("line-number");
  var firstNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  firstNumberEl.text("posx: ").attr("class", "first-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var secondNumberEl = labelEl.clone();
  secondNumberEl.text("poxy: ").attr("class", "second-number-el").append(inputEl.clone());

  var newRowEl = $("<div>").append(lineTitleEl, firstNumberEl, secondNumberEl);

  return newRowEl;
 }

 function submitted() {
  console.log("submitted");
     let buffer = 'your array is: [';
  $(".container").children("div").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find(".line-title").val();
    var firstNum = $(this).find(".first-number-el input").val();
    var secondNum = $(this).find(".second-number-el input").val();
    buffer += '{"posx":'+ firstNum + ',"posy":' + secondNum+',"text":"'+ title +'"}';
     buffer += ']';
     console.log(buffer);
  })

 }
 </script>
 <style>
 .line-title {
  width: 259px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  clear: left;
 }

 .line-number {
  width: 45px;
 }

 .container {
  margin: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <fieldset style=" margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
   <!--<div>enter amount of text + number boxes:
      <input id="amount" step="1" style=" width: 45px;" type="number" value="1">
    </div>-->
   <div class="container"></div><button class="add-row-btn">Add row</button> <button class="remove-row-btn">Remove row</button> <input class="button" id="submitBtn" style="margin-left: 85%;" type="button" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```